# Developing web application using Objective-C on FreeBSD

Tags: objective-c, clang, freebsd, gnustep

I saw that the Clang 3.0 port includes Objective-C as a development language, and furthermore, I also found this port "libobjc2-1.6" (Replacement Objective-C runtime supporting Obj-C 2 features) and "ofc-0.8.1_5" (The Objective-C Foundation Classes library).

Let's say we are considering to use Objective-C on FreeBSD to develop a web-based application (vs. using Java and running it on Tomcat/Glassfish), how do we approach it?

Does Objective-C development actually work on FreeBSD (9.0)?

What are the things (frameworks/library) to download and install?

What IDE?

As I mentioned that let's say we intend to develop a web application, what are the library?/libraries (We also saw that there is "GNUstepWeb" - successor to WebObjects - is this the web library we should consider? Is this the ONLY ONE - what about other alternatives? Further, can GNUstep/GNUstepWeb compile under Clang 3.0 or make use of those Objective-C ports ("libobjc2-1.6" and "ofc-0.8.1_5") mentioned above? Are those ports relavant?

Has anyone successfully done a web application project development on FreeBSD using Objective-C (and deployed on FreeBSD)?

Note: Web-based applications means it takes in HTTP (RESTful) calls and talks to a database (for traditional and/or NoSQL databases).

Comment: I just saw that it is possible to build GNUstep with clang:
http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/Building_GNUstep_with_Clang

Comment: I think the best would be to ask your question in the gnustep-dev ML.

Answer (score 1):

There is http://cocotron.org, a port (more like re-write) of Apple's runtime for Objective-C.

I still could advice against using ObjC for web stack. I did that previously, and I must say that it involves a big chunk of pretty common code that you will need to implement for basic HTTP server functionality.

Also, Cocotron is not really that fast (as a runtime). It's ok for desktop applications, but web world is much more restrictive.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing a library supporting this using FastCGI to interface the server called CGIKit (https://github.com/xcvista/CGIKit) and it works on GNUstep instead of Cocoatron.

Answer (score 0):

you may look at sope and sogo http://sope.opengroupware.org/en/build/thirdparty.html

Answer (score 0):

[Someone seems having success building Objective-C program for FreeBSD 9.x](http://brilliantobjc.blogspot.kr/2012/12/cocoa-on-freebsd.html)

You don't need to worry about the IDE if you don't mind using Apple. It would be possible to write on Mac, and run on FreeBSD. (personally I think this is the best of both world) IMO, if there's a server OS with Objective-C ready, FreeBSD will be first one.

More serious problem is libraries and frameworks. We don't have much options in Objective-C for web server development even on OSX. But we can wrap existing C/C++ libraries, (just as like many great node.js, Python, Ruby libraries do) and I think we may can get bunch of options with small efforts.

Some people worry about security. And I always wonder how many foundational programs on the network are written in C/C++ and other languages.

Comment: I doubt that FreeBSD would be the first one. Unless you mean Objective-C 2.0 ready (of course, the runtime's author is in FreeBSD Core Team). ie. since most Objective-C web libraries for GNUstep world were developed during the GCC time.

Comment: @FredFrith-MacDonald Ah yeah. You're right. I forgot legacy runtime. And I don't think we can use legacy GNUstep libraries as is. So if it becomes possible, I will happily 
write my own.

Comment: Those old frameworks are in production and they may need some patches or may not. They are well maintained so I have no idea why you'd describe them as 'legacy'. In what basis that you think you cannot use those libraries? You didn't even try, did you?

Comment: @FredFrith-MacDonald It's because you told me those frameworks are depending on legacy (GCC) runtime, so I thought it's not been updated. But if they gets update for modern runtime, there's no technical reason not to use them.

Comment: @FredFrith-MacDonald This is out of context, but the license also would be considered for commercial product. I tend to avoid GPL'ed software to avoid any possible legal issue. Anyway, this is more like to political or legal issue than technical.

Comment: I didn't tell you they were depending on old runtime. And LGPL is not GPL so it's a good start to make sure you know they are totally different.

Comment: @FredFrith-MacDonald OK. I see. About the legacy stuff, that's my mistake. For the license, (IMO) LGPL is conditional offering for close-source product. And I fear the unknown future situation that I cannot satisfy the condition, so all my investment on the code suddenly becomes unusable.

Answer (score 0):

In his blog post [“Using Objective-C on the server”](http://blog.securemacprogramming.com/2012/03/using-objective-c-on-the-server/) Graham Lee describes how to set up a minimal GNUStep-WebApp. Obviously, the build instruction for GNUstep-make would differ, but other than that this seems like a nice starting point.

He wrote [several other posts](http://blog.securemacprogramming.com/category/webobjects/) (jQuery, AJAX) further exploring GSW.